# Deriving the first instance of a specific node type in a tree structure query using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am designing an Electrical design software that will model an electrical utility system from the incoming Power Utility right down to the individual circuits such as computers and coffee machines.

I want to give each component of the system a dedicated table. eg. Transformers, Loads, cables, PowerPanels (called buses in this example).

Each component can be connected to one or many other components. I am using a parent/child table to manage the connections and plan to use a CTE to derive the hierarchical tree structure for a given component.

The voltage supplying any component in the system will be derived by finding the first instance of a transformer or a utility in the tree.

I have developed a query that can handle this as demonstrated below.

However, this only works for selecting one component in the CTE. I am looking for a way to select all buses and their connected voltage (nearest trafo or Utility). The only solution I can come up with is to use a table function on the above query. Is there a better way of doing this.

```
CREATE TABLE #componentConnection
    (componentConnectionID int, parentComponentID varchar(4), childComponentID int)
;

INSERT INTO #componentConnection
    (componentConnectionID, parentComponentID, childComponentID)
VALUES
    (1, '13', 18),
    (2, '13', 19),
    (3, '13', 20),
    (4, '13', 21),
    (5, '13', 22),
    (6, '13', 23),
    (7, '14', 24),
    (8, '14', 25),
    (9, '14', 26),
    (10, '14', 27),
    (11, '14', 28),
    (12, '14', 29),
    (13, '15', 30),
    (14, '15', 31),
    (15, '15', 32),
    (16, '15', 33),
    (17, '15', 34),
    (18, '15', 35),
    (19, '16', 36),
    (20, '16', 37),
    (21, '16', 38),
    (22, '16', 39),
    (23, '16', 40),
    (24, '16', 41),
    (25, '1', 5),
    (27, '5', 13),
    (28, NULL, 1),
    (29, '18', 6),
    (30, '6', 11),
    (31, '11', 7),
    (32, '7', 14)
;


CREATE TABLE #component
    (componentID int, componentName varchar(8), componentType varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO #component
    (componentID, componentName, componentType)
VALUES
    (1, 'Utility1', 'utility'),
    (2, 'Utility2', 'utility'),
    (3, 'utility3', 'utility'),
    (4, 'utility4', 'utility'),
    (5, 'Cable1', 'cable'),
    (6, 'Cable2', 'cable'),
    (7, 'Cable3', 'cable'),
    (8, 'Cable4', 'cable'),
    (9, 'Cable5', 'cable'),
    (10, 'Cable6', 'cable'),
    (11, 'Trafo1', 'trafo'),
    (12, 'Trafo2', 'trafo'),
    (13, 'Bus1', 'bus'),
    (14, 'Bus2', 'bus'),
    (15, 'Bus3', 'bus'),
    (16, 'Bus4', 'bus'),
    (17, 'Bus5', 'bus'),
    (18, 'cub1', 'cir'),
    (19, 'cub2', 'cir'),
    (20, 'cub3', 'cir'),
    (21, 'cub4', 'cir'),
    (22, 'cub5', 'cir'),
    (23, 'cub6', 'cir'),
    (24, 'cub1', 'cir'),
    (25, 'cub2', 'cir'),
    (26, 'cub3', 'cir'),
    (27, 'cub4', 'cir'),
    (28, 'cub5', 'cir'),
    (29, 'cub6', 'cir'),
    (30, 'cub1', 'cir'),
    (31, 'cub2', 'cir'),
    (32, 'cub3', 'cir'),
    (33, 'cub4', 'cir'),
    (34, 'cub5', 'cir'),
    (35, 'cub6', 'cir'),
    (36, 'cub1', 'cir'),
    (37, 'cub2', 'cir'),
    (38, 'cub3', 'cir'),
    (39, 'cub4', 'cir'),
    (40, 'cub5', 'cir'),
    (41, 'cub6', 'cir')
;

CREATE TABLE #utility
    ([utilityID] int, [componentID] int, [utlityKV] float)
;

INSERT INTO #utility
    ([utilityID], [componentID], [utlityKV])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 0.4),
    (2, 2, 0.208),
    (4, 3, 0.48),
    (5, 4, 0.208)
;

CREATE TABLE #transformer
    ([transformerID] int, [componentID] int, [facilityID] int, [transformerName] varchar(4), [transformerPrimaryTapKv] float, [transformerSecondaryTapKv] float, [transformerPrimaryKv] float, [transformerSecondaryKv] float)
;

INSERT INTO #transformer
    ([transformerID], [componentID], [facilityID], [transformerName], [transformerPrimaryTapKv], [transformerSecondaryTapKv], [transformerPrimaryKv], [transformerSecondaryKv])
VALUES
    (3, 11, 1, NULL, 0.48, 0.208, 0.48, 0.208),
    (4, 12, 2, NULL, 0.48, 0.4, 0.48, 0.4)
;

CREATE TABLE #Bus
    ([busID] int, [busTypeID] int, [componentID] int, [bayID] int, [busName] varchar(4), [busConductorType] varchar(6), [busRatedCurrent] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Bus
    ([busID], [busTypeID], [componentID], [bayID], [busName], [busConductorType], [busRatedCurrent])
VALUES
    (8, 1, 13, 1, 'bus1', 'Copper', 60),
    (9, 1, 14, 1, 'bus2', 'copper', 50),
    (10, 2, 15, 1, 'bus3', 'copper', 35),
    (11, 2, 16, 1, 'bus4', 'copper', 35),
    (13, 1, 17, 1, 'bus5', 'copper', 50)

;

WITH CTE AS (SELECT        childComponentID AS SourceID, childComponentID, 0 AS depth
                                                  FROM            #ComponentConnection
                                                  UNION ALL
                                                  SELECT        C1.SourceID, C.childComponentID, c1.depth + 1 AS depth
                                                  FROM            #ComponentConnection AS C INNER JOIN
                                                                           CTE AS C1 ON C.parentComponentID = C1.childComponentID)
    SELECT  childComponentID,b.busName, min(depth)
    --,c.componentType
    ,isnull(t.transformerSecondaryKv,u.utlityKV) kV
     FROM            CTE AS CTE1 
     join #Component c
     on CTE1.SourceID = c.componentID 
     left join #Utility u
     on CTE1.SourceID = u.componentID 
     left join #Transformer t
     on CTE1.SourceID = t.componentID 
     LEFT JOIN #Bus b
     on cte1.childComponentID = b.componentID 
     where busName is not null and c.componentType in ('Utility','trafo')
     group by childComponentID,b.busName,isnull(t.transformerSecondaryKv,u.utlityKV)
     order by depth
```

The desired result would be as follows for a Bus. I want to list all Buses and their associated Voltage. I would select all from the Bus table and derive the voltage from the heirarchical structure

Result

```
BusName | Voltage
Bus 1   |  0.4
Bus 2   |  0.208
Bus 3   |  etc
```

Comment: Can you please add the expected results and your query?

Comment: I have updated the question to add the desired result

Comment: I think you can drop your `and c.componentType =` condition from your joins, the join with the table on the ID is enough to limit the rows.  If you want only bus IDs in your output, you can also inner join your bus table on its ID field.  If you then want the lowest depth, you can do that with the MIN() function or TOP or however else you want.

Comment: Thanks Beth. I have cleaned up the example per your recommendations and added the bus to select. However, I need to find first node with utility or trafo based on the depth. I am struggling to group by here as I need to get the min(depth) and return the kV. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: do I have to run a subquery on the results of the group by min(depth) to get the kV value?